# Formulários e Ficheiros

Tags: php, arquivo, formulário, csv

Estou a fazer um formulário em que basicamente acedo a um ficheiro `.txt` no formato CSV em que contem alguns artigos e respectivos preços (ex:queijo,2.10).

O programa apresenta a lista numa tabela, e por baixo aparecem dois campos que pedem "Artigo" e "Quantidade", agora qual a melhor maneira para fazer com que o programa procure o artigo no ficheiro, e diga se o mesmo existe ou não, caso o produto exista, apresentar o total da multiplicação da quantidade com o valor do produto, que está na segunda coluna do ficheiro `.txt`.

Por exemplo, Produto: Queijo, Quantidade: 10, apresentar 10x o preço do queijo de total em baixo.

PS: Os formulários com os campos "Artigo" e "Quantidade" desaparecem após serem preenchidos.

Até agora meu código está assim:

```
<?php

$br="</br>";
$file=fopen("produtos.txt","r");

echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Artigos</th><th>Preco</th>";
while(!feof($file)) {
$registo=fgetcsv($file);

    echo"<tr>";
    echo"<td>".$registo[0]."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$registo[1]."</td>";
    echo"</tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
fclose($file);
?>

<?php
if ($_POST) {
    echo "Produto: ".$_POST["produto"]."<br>";
    echo "Quantidade ".$_POST["quantidade"]."<br>";
}
else {
?>

<form action="eta15.php" method="post">
Produto <input type="text" name="produto"><br>
Quantidade <input type="text" name="quantidade"><br>
<input type="Submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
</form>

<?php 
}
?>
```

Deixo dois printscreens, espero que ajudem na minha questão do resultado em que estou:

Formulário de pesquisa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Formulário de resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isso basta fazer uma condição de pesquisa, se o produto for igual ao pesquisado então calcula o total da multiplicação do preço pela quantidade:

```
//...
$produto = isset( $_POST["produto"]    ) ? $_POST["produto"]    : "";
$qtd     = isset( $_POST["quantidade"] ) ? $_POST["quantidade"] : ""; 
$total   = 0;
$precoUN = 0;

while(!feof($file)) 
{
    $registo=fgetcsv($file);

    if( $produto == $registo[0] )
    {
        $total   = $registo[1] * $qtd;
        $precoUN = $registo[1];
    }

    echo"<tr>";
    echo"<td>".$registo[0]."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$registo[1]."</td>";
    echo"</tr>";

}
//...
if ($_POST) 
{
    echo "Produto:    ". $produto ."<br>";
    echo "Quantidade: ". $qtd     ."<br>";
    echo "Total       ". $total   ."<br>";
    echo "Preço/UN    ". $precoUN ."<br>";

    if ( $total > 0 ) 
    {
        echo "<br> O Produto selecionado existe";
    }
    else 
    { 
        echo "O Produto nao existe";
    }
}
//...
```

Comment: Esta é a resposta mais acertada à questão que aqui foi colocada, apresenta um código limpo e profissional!
Obrigado pelo tempo disponibilizado e pela ajuda!

Comment: Neste caso, se eu quisesse que a tabela desaparecesse depois do submit, onde a tinha que colocar ?

Comment: @MarioCaeiro dentro de um if, assim: `if( ! $_POST ){ //tabela }`

Comment: Não percebi, tenho o codigo assim: http://pastebin.com/k32byUWD
A Tabela está em cima, como a tinha que colocar mesmo ?

Comment: @MarioCaeiro colocar o código que impirme a tabela dentro de uma condição, se não foi feito POST então imprime:  `if ( ! isset( $_POST ) ) {  echo "<table border='1'> ........ echo "</table>"; }`

Comment: tentei isso, mas quando apresenta valores deixa de calcular e acusa que nao existe o produto, mas a tabela desaparece

Comment: @MarioCaeiro esqueci-me que tens ai a pesquisa, vai ser complicado assim...